# Entrust @role and @permission directives not rendering in blade, laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, entrust

Let me tell you the points.

1. I am using Entrust by https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/
2. I am using multi-auth i.e I have 2 guards as `web` for `users` table and `admin` guard for `admins` table.
3. In `admins` table there are users with multiple permissions (roles too).
4. The `permission` middelware has the code

   if (!Auth::guard('`admin`')->user()->can(explode('|', $permissions)))
5. In my `Admin` model, I have used `use EntrustUserTrait;`
6. Middelware `permission` is working fine on `routes.php` the only problem I am facing is if any `Admin User` does not have permission suppose `can-create` then the html written in the that block should be hidden in blade file.

`@permission('can-create')
Lorem Ipsum...
@endpermission`

the above blade directives are not highlighted as @if or @foreach etc.

I think there might be something due multi-auth I am using, since Entrust takes `users` table by default.

Kindly enlighten me, considering this situation.

Comment: I guess, https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar this might be helpuf. Ensure you have correct auth and role while entering the page. By the way, try some `dd()` right inside blade.

Comment: I have used dd() here. e.g {{ dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user()->can('can-create-forum-category')) }}
Here if the admin user has permission to create forum category, then it successfully returns true or false, but I don't need this approach everywhere, what I need is to use is, @permission('can-create-forum-category'), which is just rendered as plain HTML in blade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got the solution to this issue. Please go through the steps I have used.

1. Run command `php artisan make:provider EntrustCustomServiceProvider`
2. go to `app/Providers/EntrustCustomServiceProvider.php`
3. `Use Auth;` and Write in the `boot` function

   public function boot()
   {

   ```
   \Blade::directive('permission', function($expression) {
       return "<?php if (Auth::guard('admin')->user()->can({$expression})) : ?>";
   });

   \Blade::directive('endpermission', function($expression) {
       return "<?php endif; ?>";
   });
   ```

   }
4. Add this entry in providers array in `config/app.php` : `App\Providers\EntrustCustomServiceProvider::class,`

One more thing, many of the phpstorm users may wonder why these directives are not auto-populated in the editor then please note, whenever we add custom blade directives, we need to add these in the blade plugin of the phpstorm editor.
Here is the solution:

1. Go to `File->settings->php->Blade`
2. uncheck `Default Settings`, go to `Directives` tab.
3. Add new directive using `+`
4. Enter the directive name,here `permission` without using @, check `has parameter`
5. Enter `<?php if (Auth::guard('admin')->user()->can(` in prefix and `)):?>` in suffix
6. same do for `@endpermission` without adding any parameters.

I hope this is helpful for someone like me :)